# else is an unexpected token js

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm very rusty at JS so I may be messing up my syntax but for some reason else if just won't work. This is the code snippet:

```js
if (command == 'flip') {
    console.log("flippin")
    var coin = Math.round(Math.random())

    if (coin == 1); {
        coin = "Tails"
    } 
    else if (coin == 0); {
        coin = "Heads"
    }
    else if (!coin == "1" || !coin == "2"); {
        console.log("hey you messed up, coin = ", coin)
        coin = "Uh Oh... Something went really really wrong here so I can't help ya here :( blame my dev not me man. Don't worry I already reported this problem to him!"  
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

**strong text**
(The rest of the code is just a discord bot I am working on)

Comment: You have an extra semicolon here: `else if (coin == 0);`. Remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semi-colons from after your conditions and check out the [if...else page on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to see the expected syntax.

```js
const command = 'flip'
if (command == 'flip') {
  console.log("flippin")
  var coin = Math.round(Math.random())

  if (coin == 1) {
    coin = "Tails"
  } else if (coin == 0) {
    coin = "Heads"
  } else if (!coin == "1" || !coin == "2") {
    console.log("hey you messed up, coin = ", coin)
    coin = "Uh Oh... Something went really really wrong here so I can't help ya here :( blame my dev not me man. Don't worry I already reported this problem to him!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colons on the if statments.